# Can every uncountable cardinal be realized as a cofinality?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, cardinals, ordinals

I searched a bit, but couldn't find an answer to the question in the title.

Given an uncountable cardinal $\kappa$ is there an ordered set with cofinality equal to $\kappa$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes. There is an extra condition required for an uncountable cardinal to appear as a cofinality (that is, the least order-type of a unbounded subset.) Namely the cardinal must be **regular**.

**Definition:** A cardinal $\lambda$ is regular, provided, every subset with order-type strictly less than $\lambda$ is bounded.

**Proposition**: If $(L, <)$ is a totally ordered set, then the cofinality of $L$ is regular.

**Proof:** Let $\lambda$ be the cofinality of $L$; moreover assume $C=\{a_\alpha: \alpha \in\lambda \} \subset L$ is cofinal with order-type $\lambda$. Then, every unbounded subset $X\subset \lambda$ of $\lambda$ generates a new cofinal subset of $L$, namely $C_X = \{ a_\alpha: \alpha\in X\} \subset C$. Moreover, this new cofinal subset, $C_X$, has the same order-type as $X$; by the minimality of $\lambda$, each cofinal subset $C_X$ must again have order-type $\lambda$, establishing the regularity of $\lambda$.

### Edit:

I just realized that you didn't specify that the order needed to be total. If you remove that requirement, then **yes** every uncountable cardinal can occur as the cofinality of an ordered-set.

For example:

The set of finite decreasing sequences of ordinals less than $\aleph_\omega$, ordered by end-extension has cofinality $\aleph_\omega$ (here the cofinality reverts back to the least *cardinality* of a cofinal subset.)

Comment: Ah ha, then $\aleph_{\omega}$, being singular, would be a cardinal that is not realizable as a cofinality.

Comment: @RobertThingum Actually, if you aren't restricted to orders which are total; then you can have ordered sets with cofinality $\aleph_\omega$.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that? I am primarily interested in total orders, but would still be interested. To clarify though, if we are restricted to total orders then it's regular cardinals or bust?

Comment: @RobertThingum correct.

Comment: @RobertThingum I added an example of an ordered set with singular cofinality.